# Moving Ground in between resistors in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, ground

What happens when you move Ground to the given point? How does it affect the Voltage and the Resistors after moving it in the circuit?

[image: The Circuit]

Missing values:

- .Current (I)= 30mA
- (V.R1)= 15V
- (V.R2)= 3.6V
- (V.R3)= 10.7V
- (V.R4)= 10.7V
- (V.R5)= 12.6V
- (V.R6)= 7.4V

Answer (score 1):

In most circuits, Gound is simply the point we choose to call Zero Volts, and use as a reference when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit.

By moving the Ground as you show, the voltages across each resistor will not change, but the voltages at the points between the resistors, relative to Ground/Zero Volts will change.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit is just a voltage divider with a bunch of different resistors. Even if you move the ground point, it's still just a voltage divider.

The tricky part is that usually, we use the term 'Ground' as a reference to the lowest voltage level in the circuit. However, the physics is exactly the same if we label any other point in the circuit as 'Ground' instead.

Because the resistors are all in series, we can sum them up to find the equivalent resistance, Req (2000 ohms), of the circuit. Req is the same, regardless of where we label 'Ground'.

From Ohm's law and Req, we know that the current through the circuit is 30mA. We can find the voltage drop across each resistor by multiplying 30mA times each resistor value. This gives us the voltage drop across each resistor.

Then, starting at GND, and moving around the circuit, we can sum up the voltage drops for each resistor, and the voltage gain from the source:

(0V) --R4-- (-10.7V) --R5-- (-23.3V) --R6-- (-30.7V) --V1-- (29.3V) --R1-- (14.3V) --R2-- (10.7V) --R3-- 0V

The important thing is that no matter where you start, when you finish going around the circuit, the voltage level ends back where you started.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff88F1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The same circuit but with differing ground points.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The CircuitLab DC solver shows the voltages with respect to the ground point.*

Rather than calculate or measure the voltage drop across each resistor it is common to measure voltages with respect to the ground. The voltage drop on each resistor can, of course, be calculated by the difference in potential (relative to ground) at each end of the resistor.

> How does it affect the voltage and the resistors after moving it in the circuit?

The voltage *across* the resistor doesn't change but the voltage with respect to ground does.